# Filter child categories by id

Tags: category, category-tree

I would like to exclude a number of child categories from my catalogue collection in order to amend a mega menu I am creating.

I have tried the following:

```
$subAcc = $acc->getChildrenCategories();
$subAcc->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('nin' => array(321, 322)));
```

But this errors. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: use entity_id instead of category_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change  `category_id` to `entity_id` and code:

```
$subAcc = $acc->getChildrenCategories();
$subAcc->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => array(321, 322)));
```